# HDMI with Sony Bravia: Unsupported Signal

Tags: display, hdmi

I recently got a Sony Bravia HD TV but can't connect it to my Ubuntu laptop. I've a Dell with Intel GM965 Graphics. When I connect to the TV using an HDMI cable, it says:

```
Unsupported signal, check device output.
```

It is detected by Ubuntu just fine. I tried with different resolutions in the display settings but couldn't get it to work. Also, I couldn't find settings for refresh rate (I'm on 11.10).

The TV/Cable is fine as PS3 works perfectly well.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the output of `xrandr -q`?

Answer (score 1):

Guess what, I replace the HDMI cable and it worked. It's quite weird though. PS3 works with the old cable but laptop doesn't. Both of them work with the new cable.

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this since it was a hardware issue, glad you got it sorted though!